# Can "Karst" be expressed as area or spot?

Tags: word-choice

Preliminary research found 112 caves in **Karst areas/spots** (?) in X regency

Can Karst be expressed as:

Karst areas or Kars spots?

Comment: N-Grams is good for this sort of question:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=karst+areas%2Ckarst+spots%2Ckarst+regions%2Ckarst+spot&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ckarst%20areas%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bkarst%20areas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BKarst%20areas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BKarst%20Areas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ckarst%20regions%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bkarst%20regions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BKarst%20regions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BKarst%20Regions%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

> Preliminary research found 112 caves in karst **areas**
>   Preliminary research found 112 caves in the karst **region**
>
> Preliminary research found 112 caves **at** karst **spots**

However, karsts are areas unless you are using **spot** informally

Comment: I would like to use your examples to improve my answer. Or, vice versa, you could borrow from my explanation to fill out your examples. Combining your examples as clarification makes a very good answer. I've upvoted your answer because it adds nicely to a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the usage is correct. Karst is, by definition, an area, and it is not a single point.

"Spot" can be used to mean anything from a single point to an area covering many square miles. A "spot" is a singularity - there is something that is different about it vs the surrounding areas. Thus, size may not be of particular importance. Although common usage is for small areas, probably 6" in diameter or less, this is not essential. "Spot" can be used for very large items, e.g. "The Great Red Spot" on Jupiter.

The author is, without doubt, attempting to avoid misunderstanding, and has thus included the word "spot". In this case, "spot" would be synonymous with area.